# How to set margins for ImageButtons in a GridView?

Tags: android

I have a GridView populated with ImageButtons at runtime.   Some buttons are smaller than others and they hug the top of their row;  I want them centered in their row.   I think I could accomplish this with a margin (or maybe even gravity) but programmatically I don't see any way to do this.

The usual advice is to use LayoutParams, but the layout params available via GridView's LayoutParams are very limited and don't include margin or gravity.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: But with LayoutParams, you can set the padding. Set the padding accordingly. Remember the padding is in px so don't forget to convert it to dip or the measure you want.

Comment: Padding is not applicable to this problem -  it only affects the  internal position of the CONTENTS of the view - it would have no affect on the position of the top edge of the ImageButton in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are a part of a linearlayout of any other layout view, on the image, you could use something like :

```
<View 
    android:gravity="center-vertical"/>
```

This will handle the view to be in the center of the vertical stretch. If you use :

```
android:layout_gravity
```

then it will position it according to its parent.